# Suddenly Siri started to drain battery on iPhone SE (iOS 12.3.1)

Tags: iphone, ios

About 4 days ago I noticed a firm and steady battery drain on my iPhone SE, that the Settings attribute to Siri (see screenshot below).

I did not (or don't remember doing) do any changes in settings at that time.

I installed a few apps recently, so I deleted some of them and offloaded the rest.
I also disabled some Siri related settings (like suggestions).
Apparently (some of) the above stopped the drain for about an hour, but then it continued. So... looking for solutions.

I almost never user Siri. Like once a week maybe, usually even less. (I use it mostly for testing as in "I wonder if Siri can do this" - the answer is usually "no, it can't")

[image: screenshot]

Comment: The screenshot just shows that during that 1 hour Siri used the battery the most.  What do you see when you select "Last 10 days" (instead of 24 hours) and the entire Battery Level is highlighted?  Does is show Siri is always using the highest battery?

Comment: @fsb All 10 days: Siri is at top with 75%. Individual day selected: 60-74% for Siri from Tuesday to Saturday, then Sunday: 92%, Monday: 82% , Tuesday: 87%, Wednesday: 53%, today(Thursday): 73%  Note: yesterday i tried some solutions, apparently they worked a bit, since it went down to 53%. Siri is always the top bat user.

Comment: Do you use Siri to do text dictation or read from websites or books?

Comment: @fsb I used it months ago once for dictating. Never for reading.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Non-solutions**:

- turning Siri Suggestions off
- turning Siri off "completely"
- playing a song in iTunes/Music (suggested [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/7961206?answerId=32691051022#32691051022) by DRH255)

These made no change.

**Solution**:

- disable the option Settings / General / Keyboard / Enable Dictation (got the hint [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/aizdh0/siri_drained_my_iphone_x_battery_overnight/eerpo5z/) and in the above link)

Funny thing, I did not have that option at all, because it appears only when a keyboard language that supports it is added. So I had to add "English (United Kingdom)" to my keyboards, then the dictation option appeared, I turned it off and... the problem is gone.

PS: [This post on reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/ios/comments/beunys/the_dictationsiri_battery_drain_bug_tested_over_1/) suggests it is not really draining the battery, only the indicator is showing the wrong value....

***edit***: this seems to (also) be the case. I left my iPhone to drain the battery completely and when it reached 1% it kept going for 5 more hours, always showing 1%. Before that it decreased by 2-3%each hour.

PPS: It still uses about 15% during night, which is too much according to some, but that is probably a separate problem.